# use iText to read pdf(C#), But I can't find the dynamic link library

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I already use iText to generate pdf, but now I need to read pdfs(no pictures, only some string)
I have found the example code. Here is the website: http://www.ujihara.jp/iTextdotNET/examples/Chap0112.cs

```
using com.lowagie.text;
using com.lowagie.text.pdf
```

But i can't find `com.lowagie.text` dll through the Internet. I can only find the Java library. I have browsed http://itextpdf.com/, but I didn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is an error in the example - try using iText.text and iText.text.pdf instead.

Comment: I have tried using iText.text and iText.text.pdf, but i still got some  error.maybe the dll version is too old

Comment: Huh! The example uses a very old version of the DLL, v1.4.6.x, which can be downloaded from their downloads page. http://www.ujihara.jp/iTextdotNET/. If using that version, the example above even don't need to be edited. It works as is, without modifying namespaces.

Comment: thx. i have solved this problem. i downloaded the newest itextsharp dll.

Comment: i also  changed the code
    using iTextSharp.text;
    using iTextSharp.text.pdf;